# Mist started re-syncing and ethers are gone

Tags: mist, ether, synchronization

I downloaded the  blockchain with `geth --fast --cache=1024` option and size of my blockchain data after download of `2412706 blocks` was around 10.9GB. I imported my accounts to keystore files and accounts appeared there, but **ethers were gone**. I restarted my wallet, and it started syncing again, still showing `2380606 blocks left`, and my chaindata foder has reached around 11GB. Why is Wallet resyncing? And why Ethers are gone?

 I am using latest Ethereum wallet 0.8.6.

Comment: I am pretty sure I used --fast option in both cases.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it's resyncing, but don't wory about your ETH, it's still there, your client just doesn't know about it. Keep in mind that if you can see your balance on a block explorer like http://etherscan.io, your ether is safe

Comment: etherscan.io shows my ethers but why Mist is not able to show.Even geth displays the balance to be 0. I have synced to the block which had the transaction in which I received the balance.

Comment: If it's fast syncing, you won't see the balance until it's actually finished syncing