# Is there any way to know whether blockchain is downloaded normally or using --fast option

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, fast-sync

This question is related to [Mist started resyncing and ethers are gone](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/mist-started-re-syncing-and-ethers-are-gone).
I was downloading blockchain using `--fast --cache=1024`. I am surprised, inspite of using `fast sync` , my blockchain data is around 11GB. How is that possible? 
I am downloading blockchain on another machine too with same --fast option and around `1715969 blocks` are downloaded and it consumed only 4.4GB of memory which is reasonable. 
But why my previous machine has downloaded full blockchainn with 11GB data and it's resyncing and the data has reached around 15GB.
I am pretty sure I used fast syncing in both my machines. But to be sure, **is there any method by which I can know that whether my blockchain was downloaded using fast or normal sync**?

**Edit**:
I have been through [How do I tell whether the Mist/Wallet is “fast” or “full” syncing?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/how-do-i-tell-whether-the-mist-wallet-is-fast-or-full-syncing) , but it suggests to check via `ps ux | grep geth` , but what if you have stopped syncing? This command shows details of geth only if it's running.That question is about knowing whether syncing is through fast or normal mode **while syncing**.My question is about of I have **finished syncing** and I want to know whether the blockchain data was download by normal or fast mode.

Comment: I have edited the question to make clear why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: read how to check is the blockchain is synced using geth http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/how-do-you-know-your-db-is-synced-in-geth

Comment: The block chain is bloated due to the recent attacks, wait for the next fork to reduce that again.

Comment: @5chdn But, I have downloaded on both machines tommorrow only, how can one eat that much space more than second.

Comment: afaik `--fast` is only for the initial syncrhonization. it switches to normal mode once it is synchronized. If you need more disk space, consider parity fast pruning mode, which is persistent.